# Валидация данных. Правильное расположение классов валидации

Tags: c#, .net, валидация

Посмотрел замечательное видео (ИМХО) [о валидации в .NET и DDD](https://youtu.be/mMo8G3gCOtA), и у меня появился вопрос:

есть проект, где есть *пока* 2 слоя: BLL & DAL (реализован паттерн Репозиторий, есть DI (пока без IoC контейнеров), собственно, пытаюсь следовать правилам 3-х слойной архитектуры. И стоит задача валидации бизнес-логики (именно в BLL по условию, несмотря на противоречивость мнения в видео) перед вызовом CRUD методов сервиса. Почитал про FLuentValidator, но, поскольку, его лучше всего использовать именно для Presentation layer - я пока не буду его внедрять.

Что я имею сейчас: хочу сделать отдельный класс для валидации каждой конкретной сущности. Но встал вопрос: методам этих классов нужен будет доступ к БД, как это лучше сделать? Через DI нужных `IRepository<какая-то модель>` или в методах сервиса загрузить данные из БД в память и отдать коллекцией классу валидации(склоняюсь к этому варианту)?